# elastic beanstalk cli publishing .net core 5 webapi to existing Linux Environment - Multi-proj in one solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, ebcli

I'm trying to deploy .net core 5 application to Elastic Beanstalk.
I can deploy application via AWS Toolkit. But I'm trying to deploy via `EB CLI`. Because github actions works with `EB CLI`.

So when I'm trying command `eb deploy`, solution create artifact with solution root directory. How can I point to `eb deploy` command pick up **KKWebApi** project, not solution.
Many Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did you get this done?  I’m wanting to do it too.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins No, I use Visual Studio AWS Toolkit. In future I'm planning not go forward with elastic beanstalk, so I dont resolve this issue